# Extend PostgreSQL by index structure, data types, retrieval types, etc. with Java?

Tags: java, postgresql

I learned that PostgreSQL is written in C. I would like to extend it by

- a customized index structure
- a customized nearest neighbor retrieval (with various distance functions)
- custom data types

I feared so far to use PostgreSQL because it is written in C. However, I've seen on the PostgreSQL about page (http://www.postgresql.org/about/) that they support "library interfaces" e.g. for Java. Can I, thus, use Java to implement (at least) a nearest neighbor retrieval and custom data types (I guess not the index structure since it is quite low-level)?

Comment: I think the "library interface" is only for *accessing* PostgreSQL. AFAIK index types can only be implemented in C. Custom data types can - to a certain extent - be implemented in SQL (or PL/pgSQL).

Comment: Ok! Thanks for clarifying! So that means I will heave to code quite a lot in C, then :-)

Comment: Certainly a customized knn index would be C only but you really want to look at PostGIS before going there.  Same with customized index structures.  But you can do a *lot* with procedural languages regarding types and dropping to C is largely required when you need to add new indexing capabilities to existing types or the like.

Comment: btw, what are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: i'm implementing an information retrieval system into a database (for my master's thesis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer here is "it's complicated."  You can actually go quite far with a procedural language (including pl/java) but you are never going to get quite the flexibility you can get with C.  What is fundamentally missing is being able to do proper indexing support in PL/Java because one cannot create new primitives.  For quite a bit more, you may want to look at [my blog](http://ledgersmbdev.blogspot.com) although most of the examples are in pl/pgsql.

**Types**

Now you can actually get very far with PL/Java (or PL/Perl, or PL/Python, or whatever you like) but there are some things that are going to be out of reach.  This is also a very high overview of what is possible with a procedural language in the db and what is not.

There are two effective ways you can work with types in procedural languages.  You can work with domains (subtypes of primitives), or you can work with complex types (objects with properties each of which is another type, either a primitive, a domain or a complex type itself).  In general you cannot really do much in terms of indexing complex types themselves but you can index their members.  Another thing that is not safe to do is output formatting, but you can supply other functions to replace this.

For example, suppose we want to have a type for storing PNG files and processing them for certain properties in the database.  We might do this in the following way:

```
CREATE DOMAIN png_image as bytea check value like [magic number goes here];
```

We could then create a bunch of stored procedures to process the png in various ways.  For example we might look for orange near the top in a function is_sunset.  We might be able to do something like:

```
SELECT name FROM landmark l
  JOIN landmark s ON (s.name = 'San Diego City hall' 
                      and  ST_DISTANCE(l.coords, s.coords) < '20')
 WHERE is_sunset(photo)
 ORDER BY name;
```

There is no reason that is_sunset could not be handled in Java, Perl, or whatever language you like.  Since is_sunset returns a bool, we could even:

```
CREATE INDEX l_name_sunset_idx ON landmark (name) where is_sunset(photo);
```

This would speed up the query by allowing us to cache the index of names of photographs of sunsets.

What you can't do in Java is create new primitive types.  Keep in mind that things like index support is at the primitive level, and therefore you can't, for example, create a new ip address type supporting GiST indexing (not that you'd need to, since ip4r is available).

So to the extent you can re-used and work with what primitives are already existing, you can do your development in Java or whatever you like.  You are really limited only by what primitives are available, and enough people have written new ones in C you may not need to touch these at all.

**Indexes**

Index code is pretty much C only as are the primitives.  You cannot customize index behavior in a procedural language.  What you can do is work with the primitives of other developers and so forth.  This is the area where you are most likely to have to drop to C.

(Update: As I think about it, it may be possible to hook into existing index types to add support for various indexes based on other PL functions, using the `CREATE OPERATOR CLASS` and `CREATE OPERATOR` commands. I have no experience doing this though.)

**Performance**

keep in mind that PL/Java means you are running a JVM in each backend process.  In many cases if you can do a what you want to do in pl/pgsql you will get better performance.  The same goes with other languages of course too, because you need an interpretor or other environment in the backend process.

Comment: Just as a note, pl/java is a bit of C code that works as a bridge allowing you to run java code in the backend itself.  I don't know if this is something you are familiar with but it is where you'd start.  I realized I didn't clarify that in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I already heard of pl/java! From your answer, I guess that the best way to go, especially for the very internal operations (and for time critical operations), is to get used to programming in C ;-)

Comment: It depends on what you are doing.  For example if you want to re-use existing Java libraries for something like image processing, that will be different than if you are trying to create something like a variant of KNN indexing.

Comment: Yes! So, what I'm planning currently (and also executing to some extent) is implementing the core database stuff, e.g. kNN indexing, etc. in C and the feature extraction function, etc. in Java